# Integrating over similar indices in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy

I am having some trouble looping an integral over a pandas dataframe. Here is an example of the CSV I am working with:

NAME,Int,K,Z

A,0,12,50

A,1,34,50

A,2,47,35

A,3,19,31

B,0,25,28

B,1,8,3

B,2,4,27

B,3,18,10

C,0,14,15

C,1,10,19

C,2,46,1

C,3,19,41

Here is the loop I am trying:

```
def integral(DF):

    for i in DF.loc[:]:

       integral=integrate.trapz(y=DF.loc[i]['K'],x=DF.loc[i]['Int'],dx=1)

    return DF.loc[i] and integral
```

Keeps returning an error saying the column next to the index column,"NAME", is not in the index. Any help would be appreciated. To clarify, I am trying to take the integrals of the K & Z columns with "Int" being the x-axis and return both name and integral. My actual CSV is much larger than this.

Answer (score 1):

I tried out and hope this can help you a bit:-

From above answer I made the `dataframe`

```
from io import StringIO
import numpy as integrate

s = """
NAME,Int,K,Z
A,0,12,50
A,1,34,50
A,2,47,35
A,3,19,31
B,0,25,28
B,1,8,3
B,2,4,27
B,3,18,10
C,0,14,15
C,1,10,19
C,2,46,1
C,3,19,41
"""
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s), sep=',')
print(df)
```

You also need to convert to `float` to use `numpy` functionality

```
df['Int'] = df['Int'].astype(float)
df['K'] = df['K'].astype(float)
df['Z'] = df['Z'].astype(float)
del df['NAME']
```

You were passing boolean return, use `commas` instead

```
def integral(DF):

    for i in DF.loc[:].values:  #use values instead
        print(i)
        integral=integrate.trapz(y=DF.loc[i],x=DF.loc[i],dx=1)

    return DF.loc[i], integral


integral(df)

>>
(      Int     K     Z
 3.0   3.0  19.0  31.0
 19.0  NaN   NaN   NaN
 41.0  NaN   NaN   NaN, array([476.,  nan,  nan]))
```

I am not sure this kind of output you want but hope this can help.